# How to write jsonschema for nestes dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I have the file with the following json dicts, where all keys and values are strings:

```
{ N10 : 
   { code : 0123456789
     name : Holder
   }
  N11 :
   { code : 1111111111
     name : Owner 
   }
  N12 : 
   { code : 2222222222
     name : Holder
   }
}
```

My schema looks like this but it doesn't seems to work (could you give an advice as to what am I doing worng with this schema:

```
{
    $schema              :  http://json-schema.org/schema
    title                :  New project
    type                 :  object
    additionalProperties :  {
        type : string 
        required : [
            code
            name
        ]
        properties : {
            code : {
               type : string
               pattern : [0-9]
               }
            name : {
               type : string
               pattern : [a-z]
               }
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Hi! Define "it doesn't seem to work". What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? Why did you not expect that to happen? Then maybe I can help. =]

Comment: It's also helpful if you can provide your schema and instance using a share link from https://jsonschema.dev

Comment: @Relequestual when I am doing jsonschema.validate it raises HjsonDecodeError

Comment: Just to check, you realise what you've provided is not JSON, right? It's an object in javascript, but not JSON. JSON has quotes around keys and strings. What you have there looks more like YAML.

Comment: Given the issue is with your code, please provide your minimal reproduceable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Relequestual it is json code that is wewritten into hjson for more pleasant representation. I thought hjsondecoder should be able to see that thos keys and values are strings or is not?

Comment: I don't know, maybe. But what will help is if you can provide a minimal reproduceable example =]